# Using the serial port in a Ubuntu for W10 (WSL)

Tags: serial-port, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tty

I'd like to know if it is possible to establish communication via a serial port in an Ubuntu for W10 terminal using the USB interface.

Concretely, I am using a Sparkfun edge board and in this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sparkfun-tensorflow/#4), it is explained how to detect if the device is connected by checking `/dev/tty*`. However, it does not work in my testbed, nothing new appears in the directory.

Probably, it is related to using Ubuntu over Windows, but I'd like to be sure before moving to another system.

Comment: WSL has no "Linux kernel" untill now. So we can't access devices as in Linux. Wait few months, Linux kernel coming soon in WSL2.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I see, so, would it work in a virtual machine? As they execute the whole kernel...

Comment: It is not released so I can't say detailed info about it. For curiosity, read all https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old, but it should've worked then...  New devices don't show up in the directory, they're already all there, so you need to know what COM port it's on, let's say it's on COM4, then your device will be /dev/ttyS4 in linux.

I've been using this for well over a year to upload files to my MCU boards kinda like what you want to do, and as long as the device shows up as a COM interface in Windows, and isn't in use, you should be able to connect it to it in WSL as /dev/ttyS[COM#].

Hope this helps, even if it's a bit delayed.

Comment: I'll have to try this in my personal laptop, but in my work laptop, I can't see /dev/ttyS4. I'm running ubuntu on WSL2 and Windows 10 19042.1110

Comment: Yeah, this isn't working for me either.